# General formula for Differentiation Operator

Tags: derivatives, summation, recurrence-relations, differential-operators

I was considering the Operator
$$
x\,\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}
$$
and applying it $n$ times to an arbitrary function $f(x)$.
Is there a general formula for it?

I started with the first few
\begin{align}
\left(x\,\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\right)^{1} f(x) &= x f' \\
\left(x\,\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\right)^{2} f(x) &= x f' + x^2 f'' \\
\left(x\,\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\right)^{3} f(x) &= x f' + 3x^2 f'' + x^3 f''' \\
\left(x\,\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\right)^{4} f(x) &= x f' + 7 x^2 f'' + 6x^3 f''' + x^4 f'''' \\
\vdots
\end{align}
but I don't see any pattern yet.
Obviously the first and last coefficients are always $1$.

I figured if I start with any $n$ of the form
$$
\left(x\,\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\right)^{n} f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \, x^k f^{(k)}(x) \tag{1}
$$
where $a_1=a_n=1$, then recursively
\begin{align}
\left(x\,\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\right)^{n+1} f(x) &= xf^{(1)}(x) + \sum_{k=2}^n \left(k \, a_k + a_{k-1}\right) x^k f^{(k)}(x) + x^{n+1} f^{(n+1)}(x) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \left(k \, a_k + a_{k-1}\right) x^k f^{(k)}(x) \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $a_0=a_{n+1}=0$.

From (1) and (2) we get for fixed $k$ the coupled recurrence
$$
a_k(n+1) = k\, a_k(n) + a_{k-1}(n)
$$
which can be put in matrix form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} a_1(n+1) \\ a_2(n+1) \\ a_3(n+1) \\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1}(n+1) \\ a_n(n+1) \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & n-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1(n) \\ a_2(n) \\ a_3(n) \\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1}(n) \\ a_n(n) \end{pmatrix} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 &  \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & n-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & n \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \, .
\end{align}
So either I'm too stupid or there is no obvious one.

Comment: This might be relevant to your interests: Weyl Algebra. I once had to do something like this, and I was just as confused as you are. However, in my problem I only needed to know information about the first and last terms. You can make inductive arguments about those, I think.

Comment: Well the first and last terms are always one, so there is not much to do or?

Comment: I guess my question is: what do you need the general form for? It is fine if you are just curious, I was assuming you were trying to show something else and that this is a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @Diger, I don't think you're stupid. However you transformed your problem into a boundary problem, if you can solve that you can find a closed form solution.

Comment: I want to know the growth of the coefficients in order to estimate a coefficient of a series. I need radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficients are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Table_of_values).

Comment: Must have been solved before ;) Thanks. How did you know?

Comment: I recognized 1, 7, 6, 1.  :-)

Comment: You could also compute a bit further and enter the coefficients of a later row into the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C511%2C9330%2C34105%2C42525%2C22827%2C5880%2C750%2C45%2C1&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Because you look at these numbers everyday? I would not even remember one of them...

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know of this side. Very helpful.

Comment: Quoting the first page of Chapter 6 in [Concrete Mathematics](https://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025): A problem that involves the numbers ”1, 7, 6, 1” is likely to be related to $n \brace k$, and a problem that involves the numbers ”6, 11, 6, 1” is likely to be related to $n \brack k$.